# Fit the popup to his content

Tags: html, css

Hello I would like to create a popup that fits to his content. Indeed, The aim would be that depending on the choice made in the drop-down menu, different information would change. But when I try to set a height in auto, the display of the popup header is not correct as well as the popup body.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');

*{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box
}

:root{
    /* ===== Colors ===== */
    --body-color: #E4E9F7;
    --sidebar-color: #FFF;
    --primary-color: #1c1a1a;
    --primary-color-light: #F6F5FF;
    --toggle-color: #DDD;
    --text-color: #707070;

    /* ===== Transition ===== */
    --tran-02: all 0.2s ease;
    --tran-03: all 0.3s ease;
    --tran-04: all 0.4s ease;
    --tran-05: all 0.5s ease;
}

body{
    height: 100vh;
    background: var(--body-color);
}


.parameter{
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    height: auto;
    width: 300px;
    max-height: 800px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

/*Paramètre du bouton de la fenêtre modal*/
.parameter .close-modal{
    padding: 5px 20px;
    height: 10%;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0px;
    font-size: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #fff;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

/*Activation du background lors du passage de la souris*/
.parameter .close-modal:hover{
    color: #FFF;
    background: rgb(188, 15, 15);
}

/*Paramètres du texte de la modal*/
.popup-header h1{
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
}
/**/
.parameter .popup-header{
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0% 2%;
    background-color: #FFF;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

/*Paramètres du body de la popup*/
.parameter .popup-body{
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

/*Paramètres formulaire*/
.form{
    width: 100%;
}

/*Paramètres du texte de la modal*/
.form h1{
    font-size: 17px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}

/*Paramètres des entrées*/
.form .input_field{
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

/*Paramètres des labels entrées*/
.form .input_field label{
    width: 150px;
    color: #11101d;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.form .custom_select{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;    
}

.form .custom_select{
    color: #11101d;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;    
}

/*Paramètres de l'option select*/
.form .custom_select select{
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #d5dbd9;
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 1px 2px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

/*Paramètres des aires de textes*/
.form .input_field .input,
.form .input_field .textarea{
    width: 30%;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #d5dbd9;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding:1px 2px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

/*Paramètres du bouton de connection*/
.form .input_field .btn{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
    border: 0;
    background: #707070;
    color: #FFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
}

/*Paramétres hover bouton*/
.form .input_field .btn:hover{
    background: #11101d;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'"> -->
    
    <!----===== CSS ===== -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <!----===== Boxicons CSS ===== -->
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>

    <title>Sail Vision</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="modal-container-param">
        <div class="overlay">
          <div class="parameter">
            <div class="popup-header">
              <button class="close-modal modal-trigger-param">X</button>
              <h1>Paramétres de liaisons</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="popup-body">
              <div class="form">
                <h1>LIAISON UDP</h1>
                <div class="custom_select">
                  <label>Type de centrale</label>
                  <select name="select">
                    <option value="value1" selected>NMEA</option>
                    <option value="value2">NKE</option>
                    <option value="value3" >BRAVO</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
                <div class="UDP">
                  <div class="input_field">
                    <label>Numero de port IN</label>
                    <input type="text" class="input">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="input_field">
                  <input type="submit" value="Connect" class="btn">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Regards